# Is Barack Obama descended from slaves?

Tags: barack-obama, slavery

Is Barack Obama descended from slaves?

From [Japanese lawmaker apologizes for Obama 'black slave' remark](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/02/18/asia/japan-lawmaker-obama-slave/), Japanese politician Kazuya Maruyama claims that he's descended from slaves:

> "In America, a black man became president. I mean, he's in a bloodline of black people who were slaves," Kazuya Maruyama, a lawmaker from the Liberal Democratic Party (LDP), said Wednesday, during a meeting of the Upper House constitutional panel.

Meanwhile, the CNN article claims that that is not the case:

> A lawmaker from Japan's ruling political party has apologized for **inaccurately** stating that U.S. President Barack Obama is a descendant of slaves.
>
> ...
>
> Obama, the first African American U.S. president, is not a descendant of slaves. He's the son of black father from Kenya and white mother from Kansas.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this matters. Are they suggesting that slaves are somehow inherently inferior to non-slaves?

Comment: The fact that his father was from Kenya does not eliminate the possibility that some of his Kenyan ancestors were slaves, since slavery was pretty much universal in pre-industrial civilizations.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Maruyama has received a lot of criticism for his statement.

Comment: I would think most people have had slave and/or serf ancestors, if you go far enough back. Not that it matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Obama is probably descended from a black slave - but from his white mother.

From the Wikipedia article [Family of Barack Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_Barack_Obama):

> News sources reported in July 2012 that according to Ancestry.com, through research in a combination of historical documents and yDNA analysis, John Punch, the first documented African slave in the American British colonies, has been documented as likely an eleventh great-grandfather of Obama through his mother, Ann Dunham, and her Bunch ancestors

Comment: From the text of John Punch's 9 July 1640 sentencing, it seems to me that he was a servant who was given a life sentence for escaping with two other servants (a "dutchman" and a "Scotchman"), a servant who got a harsher sentence than the other two servants, probably on account of his race, but not a slave.  https://books.google.com/books?id=7b8RAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA236&dq=%22Whereas+Hugh+Gwyn+hath+by+order+from+this+Board+brought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT_aeTtYTLAhVEzmMKHfSgCG0Q6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22Whereas%20Hugh%20Gwyn%20hath%20by%20order%20from%20this%20Board%20brought%22&f=false

Comment: @DavePhd Whether or not it was called slavery then, a servant who gets punished for escaping is clearly a slave

Comment: @DavePhD: He started out as an indentured servant. English is a bit weird because such a position is called "servant" but in many cultures and/or languages at the time indentured servants and slaves are all called slaves. The difference being that an indentured servant is a time-limited slave. Imagine if someone sold you as a slave for two years - that's an indentured servant. For running away he was punished to be a servant for the remainder of his life. Which by definition is no longer an indentured servant since the time limit is lifted. By definition that's slavery.

Comment: @eigensheep one of my great-grandmothers was an indentured servant and I never thought of her as a slave, because indentured servants would agree to serve as loan repayment of money to come to America.

Comment: "Slavery" is sometimes used to mean only "chattel slavery", and sometimes more generally.

Comment: @slebetman In the sense that Americas say that the 13th amendment ended slavery, despite including the phrase "except as a punishment for crime", I don't think Punch's punishment made him a slave.  Maybe other definitions of "slave" are broader and would include people in chain gangs, those sentenced to hard labor, etc., and then he would be a slave under that type of definition.

Comment: @DavePhD: He wasn't sentenced to a chain gang or to work for the state. He was sentenced to be his employer's property for life - by that definition he was a slave. Most consider him to be the first legal slave in North America.